# Python3 gi: GtkTextBuffer core dump

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk, glade

Using Python3 with `gi.repository.Gtk`, I'm trying to display multiple text lines inside a `GtkTextView` via a `GtkTextBuffer`.

Basically, I'm dynamically adding lines using an `_addLine` method, which updates the text buffer that way (`self._lines` is an array and `self._textBuffer` is a `GtkTextBuffer`):

```
def _addLine(self, text):
    if len(self._lines) == self._maxLines:
        self._lines = self._lines[1:]
    self._lines.append(text)
    content = '\n'.join(self._lines)
    print("TIC: %d" % len(content))
    self._textBuffer.set_text(content)
    print("TAC")
```

Unfortunately, at random values of `i` (either lower or bigger than `self._maxLines`), I randomly get a core dump between "TIC" and "TAC", so when I try to set the content of the buffer.

This method is called by a threading, himself called from the constructor (after all the GUI elements are initialized):

```
def _startUpdateThread(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: self._updateLoop())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

def _updateLoop(self):
    i=0
    for l in listings.tail(self._logFile, follow=True, n=1000):
        i+=1
        print("i=%d, nLines=%d" % (i, len(self._lines)))
        self._addLine(l)
```

I'm using a Glade builder structured as below:

```
GtkWindow
  - GtkVBox
      - GtkScrolledWindow
          - GtkTextView (linked to GtkTextBuffer)
  - GtkButton (to close the window)
  - GtkTextBuffer
```

What did I do wrong? What is the cause of that core dump?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `GLib.idle_add()` when you are modifying widgets from a thread and not the GTK main loop.

In this case:

```
GLib.idle_add(self._textBuffer.set_text, content)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @elya5 I had to set that inside `updateLoop` instead of `inside addLine` to make it working.